# Fenchel-Moreau is an Involution of Convex functions on a Hilbert space?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, duality-theorems

The Fenchel-Moreau theorem states that for a function $f:X\rightarrow [-\infty,\infty]$ (not exactly $\mp \infty$) the following are equivalent.

- f is proper, lsc, and convex
- $f=f^{**}$.
  Where $f^*$ is defined by
  $$
  f^{{*}} \left( x^{*} \right) := \sup \left \{ \left. \left\langle x^{*} , x \right\rangle - f \left( x \right) \right| x \in X \right\}
  $$

If we assume that $X$ is the separable Hilbert space, then $X^*\cong X$ via the Fréchet-Riesz representation theorem, with Hilbert-space isomorphism given by 
$$
x \mapsto (y,x),
$$
where $(,)$ is the Hilbert space inner product (and not the duality pairing).  Hence, $f^*$ is a map on $X$ (and not only on $X^*$).

**Conclusion?**
In this case, the map $f\mapsto f^*$ seems to map the set of *proper, maps proper, lsc, convex functions on $X$* into itself.  Since $f^{**}=f$ then, this map is an involution.

Is this argument flawed?  Or does it seem correct?

Comment: Yes, that's all right.